# what happend in near if we deploy smart contract in already deployed smart contract address

Tags: near

NEAR smart contracts work differently than EVM based smart contracts, what happens if we deploy two different smart contract in same NEAR address. can we merge the functions of the smart contracts ? what happens if a different smart contract is deployed in same address, how to deal with that ?